# Laravel 5.4 default success or error message is not showing properly

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.4. I am facing a big problem from last few days in my app. Any error or success message is not showing properly. When I created those feature, those worked fine. All message was showing properly. But from last few days I am facing this issue. When I try to add some content, if validation fail then error message is not shows sometime and shows sometime. Same when validation is success. I can see those data stored in the database properly but success message is not shows all the time. Sometime shows.
Here is my from to create a notice

```
 {!! Form::model($single_notice,['route'=>['notice.update',$single_notice->id],'method'=>'PUT','files'=>true]) !!}
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div style="display: block;" id="rulesformitem" class="formitem">
      {{ Form::textarea('notice', null,array('class'=>'form-control notice-textarea')) }}
    </div>
  </div>
@if($single_notice->general == 'general')
  <div class="col-lg-3 text-center" style="margin-top: 15px">
     <label for="rules" id="ruleslabel">Notice For:</label>
     <br>
     <input onclick="document.getElementById('custom').disabled = true; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = false;" type="radio" name="type" value="general" checked="checked">General
     <br>
      <input onclick="document.getElementById('custom').disabled = false; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = true;" type="radio" name="type"  >Demo/Final
        <br>
        <label for="rules" id="ruleslabel">Date & Time: <br> 01-01-2017 10(hr):30(m) <small>(This format)</small> </label>
        <br>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="demoOrfinal" id="custom" >
        <br>

  </div>  
  @else
  <div class="col-lg-3 text-center" style="margin-top: 15px">
     <label for="rules" id="ruleslabel">Notice For:</label>
     <br>
     <input onclick="document.getElementById('custom').disabled = true; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = false;" type="radio" name="type" value="general">General
     <br>
      <input onclick="document.getElementById('custom').disabled = false; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = true;" type="radio" name="type"  checked="checked">Demo/Final
        <br>
        <label for="rules" id="ruleslabel">Date & Time: <br>
  {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($single_notice->demoOrfinal)->format('H:i d-m-Y') }}
        </label>
        <br>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="demoOrfinal" id="custom" >
        <br>

  </div>
  @endif
  <div class="col-lg-2 text-center" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <label>Upload File:</label>

    @if($single_notice->image_link != 'null')
    <input type="button" class="form-control" id="loadFileXml" value="Image" style="margin-bottom: 5px" onclick="document.getElementById('image').click();" />
          {{ substr(strip_tags($single_notice->image_link),0,5) }}
          {{ strlen(strip_tags($single_notice->image_link)) > 5 ? "...jpg" : "" }}
    @endif
    <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="image" name="notice_image"/>
    <input type="button" class="form-control" id="loadFileXml" value="PDF" onclick="document.getElementById('pdf').click();" />
    @if($single_notice->pdf_link != 'null')
    <small>{{ substr(strip_tags($single_notice->pdf_link),0,5) }}
          {{ strlen(strip_tags($single_notice->pdf_link)) > 5 ? "...pdf" : "" }}
    </small>

    @endif
    <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="pdf" name="notice_pdf"/>
    <button class="form-control btn-info" style="margin-top: 5px;">Update Notice</button>

  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is method to create a notice

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request);
    $teacher_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $this->validate($request,array(
        'notice'       => 'required|min:5',
        'notice_image' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        'notice_pdf'   => 'sometimes|mimes:pdf'
    ));
    if($request->type == 'general')
    {
        $this->validate($request,array(
            'type' => 'required',
        ));   
    }
    if($request->type == 'on') {
        $this->validate($request,array(
        'demoOrfinal' => 'required|date',
        ));
    }
    $add_notice = new Notice;
    $add_notice->notice      = $request->notice;
    $add_notice->general     = $request->type;
    $add_notice->demoOrfinal = $request->demoOrfinal;
    $add_notice->posted_by  = $teacher_id;
    $add_notice->image_link  = $request->notice_image;
    $add_notice->pdf_link    = $request->notice_pdf;

    if ($request->hasFile('notice_image')) {
        $file = $request->file('notice_image');
        $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $location = public_path('file/'.$filename);
        Storage::put($filename,file_get_contents($file));
        $add_notice->image_link = $filename;

    }

    if ($request->hasFile('notice_pdf')) {
        $file = $request->file('notice_pdf');
        $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $location = public_path('file/'.$filename);
        Storage::put($filename,file_get_contents($file));
        $add_notice->pdf_link = $filename;

    }
    $add_notice->save();
    Session::flash('success','Notice Has Been Posted. Thanks :-)');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Here Is my error message showing code

```
 @if(Session::has('success'))
 <div class="alert alert-success">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
 hidden="true">&times;</button>
 <strong>{{ Session::get('success') }}</strong>
 </div>
  @endif
 @if(Session::has('denger-success'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
  hidden="true">&times;</button>
 <strong>{{ Session::get('denger-success') }}</strong>
 </div>
 @endif
 @if(count($errors))
 <div class="alert alert-danger validation-error-message">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
 hidden="true">&times;</button>
<strong>Error:</strong>
<ul>
  @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>
      {{ $error }}
    </li>
  @endforeach
 </ul> 
 </div>
 @endif
```

Sorry for my poor english.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post code of one of the methods with validation & success/error messages.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot help you without code.

Comment: added code. Please see

Comment: Have you moved sessions from file to database?

Comment: yes @DimitriMostrey

Comment: Ah, then I know what the problem is. I answer it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `php artisan session:table` and `php artisan migrate`, change the .env file to `SESSION_DRIVER=database`, the ´sessions´ table is created and put into use.

The schema of sessions is as follows:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->text('payload');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->text('user_agent');
        $table->integer('last_activity');
    });
```

It happens that the text for payload is too long and the session gets lost. If you 'upgrade' to mediumtext you fix the issue.

You can either do that in the database or create a new migration `php artisan make:migration change_payload_in_sessions_table` and add:

```
Schema::table('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->mediumText('payload')->change();
    });
```

Of course you need to run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: still it is doing same problem :-(

Comment: I am taking your answer as accepted because You gave me way to solve. I have changed session from database to file again and now it is solved. Your  solution should work for others . So I have marked this as solved. Thank you soo much for helping me.

Comment: As you are probably working in a test environment, in the `config/session.php` file, change `'lottery' => [2, 100],` to `'lottery' => [0, 100],`. That could be another reason why it sometimes doesn't works.

Comment: You could also use `return redirect()->back()->with('success','...');` or `->with(['success' => '...'])` instead of `Request::flash(...)`